# Change the font size after the first chapter/section

Tags: latex, pdflatex

The command \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} changes the font size of the entire document.

However, I like to maintain the table of content and other summaries in 12pt, but after the first chapter I like to change to 14pt.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can change font size using `\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont` (the first number is the point-size of the font, the second number is the space in points between lines: this becomes the value of `\baselineskip`)

But you can also use `\tiny`, `\small`, `\scriptsize`, `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` and `\Huge` (and the corresponding environments (e.g., `\begin{small}` ... `\end{small}`).